# How to have one input field replace another when the initial is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, authentication

I am making a simple login form for a website, initially, the username field will show with the submit button. When the submit button is pressed, the username form should disappear and the password form should replace it. I have the following code:

### HTML

```
<!-- Username form -->
    <div id="form1">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <input type="submit" value="" onclick="switchForm()">
    </form>
    </div>
<!-- Password form -->
    <div id="form2">
    <form>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="" onclick="#">
    </form>
```

### Javascript

```
 function switchForm() {
        document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
}
```

Don't worry about the form not doing anything, I will worry about that later. I just need help with the transition. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly did the "java" tag have to do with this question? What is your question or problem? It seems this code would work.

Comment: I couldn't get the code to work for some reason. And I removed the "java" tag.

Comment: You need to do 2 things: make the password form be invisible and also you don't need a submit but a button for first button. See my answer for sample.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that `swithForm()` is defined and replace `<input type="submit" value="" onclick="switchForm()">` with `<input type="button" value="" onclick="switchForm()">` otherwise it will submit your form instead of executing the `onclick` event. You've also to set `form2` to hidden on load.

```
<script>
function switchForm() {
        document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
}    
</script>
<!-- Username form -->
    <div id="form1">

        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            <input type="button" value="asdfs" onclick="switchForm()" />
    </div>
<!-- Password form -->
    <div id="form2" style="display: none;">
    <form>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="aaa" onclick="#" />
    </form>
```

Check out my working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3UcJV/

Comment: +1 I just checked and it's the exact same thought process :) . You do know that phrase on movies: "any similarity to actual persons living or dead is purely coincidental" .

Comment: @GuyT. Good answer, but you should copy the fiddle code to your answer so folks don't have to leave the site unless they want to play with it.

Comment: @Alright I will do this in the future, both of you, thank you for the comment :)